# I can't display the array passed in by the servlet in jsp

Tags: arrays, jsp, servlets

Such as the title

It may be wrong from the assignment.There are comments in the code below。

servlet

```
 String[] backJsp=(String[])dataBack.toArray(new String[dataBack.size()]);
    request.setAttribute("dataArray", backJsp);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

jsp

```
<% String[] dataJsp=(String[])request.getAttribute("dataArray");%>//System also reported an error when I deleted the following code.
        <% if(dataJsp.length>0) //This line of code system reports an error
            {
                for(int i=0;i<dataJsp.length;i++)
                {
                    out.print(dataJsp[i]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                }
            }%>
```

the following is the right answer

```
<%
            String [] dataJsp = (String [])request.getAttribute("dataArray");
            if(dataJsp==null)
            {
                out.print("please input data...");
            }else
            {
                for(String s:dataJsp)
                {
                    out.print(s+"&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                }
            }
        %>
```

Comment: what `error` did you got post that as well .

Comment: I've solved it and I have added the modified source code.the reason is that i did't tell system what to output when it has not data